# query builder equivalent of Model::query();

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Good day, please, for some reasons I have to use query builder instead of Eloquent, the reason been that the name of my model is KidsCafe and if I use Eloquent, it will search for a table with  **myapp.kidscaves**, but the name of the table is **kidscafes** this is throwing errors, so I have to use query builder in my interaction with the db.

Now, I have to implement search functionality, so how do I implement something like this using query builder

```
$kids = KidsCafe::query();
```

My question is how do I implement **query();** using query builder, and also is there another way I can use eloquent without it

thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of error is it throwing?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myapp.kidscaves' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `kidscaves` where `kidscaves`.`deleted_at` is null)

Comment: @GazmendSahiti , this is the error when I use eloquent on it, that is why all my query has been on query builder, but I don't know the syntax to use for query()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually specify a table name by defining a table property on your model:

```
class KidsCafe extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'kidscafes';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it solves my problem , but is there no other query builder syntax that is equivalent to eloquent **Model::query();**

Comment: @KINGSLEYOKPARA Great news!. You can use query builder without the "Model" like this  DB::table('kidscafes')->get(); 
Check Laravel docs for more details https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the setTable() function do dynamically use another table's name, something like this -

```
$kidscafes = new KidsCafe;
$kidscafes->setTable('kidscafes');
```